# Using dynamic file in a package

Tags: python, package

I'm creating a python package which will be imported in other python projects. I'm using some configuration in this package which is stored in a yaml file (config.yaml). the point is, this config file should be created for each project which are importing the package.

My question is how can I specify the dynamic path for the yaml file in package (it is suppose to be in root of projects)? I tried to specify path through the environment variable but no success ( because this variable should be set at the time of installation the project and I couldn't figure it out).

in package:

```
with open('config.yaml', 'r') as file:
    self.parameter = yaml.safe_load(file)
```

tried :

```
with open(os.environ.get('ALERT_CONFIG_FILE_PATH'), 'r') as file:  # this line need to be replaced by a variable which points to config.yaml in project
    self.parameter = yaml.safe_load(file)
```

Comment: It's not a common setup to be able to write to python package directories after initial installation.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm. Yes , agree. just try to find a way to pass the path of yaml file to package by using a way like environment variable